# Custom messages for Alert Rules in ElasticSearch, Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have created a Rule (Elasticsearch query) into Stack Management > Rules

**Select an index and time field**

```sql
INDEX operations*
```

**Define your query using Query DSL**

```json
{  
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "o": "user-input"
    }
  }
}
```

**Set the threshold and time window**

```sql
IS ABOVE 64
FOR THE LAST 15 minutes
```

Set the number of documents to send

```sql
SIZE 0
```

Test Query deliver...

***Query matched 30 documents in the last 15m.***

My connector is a custom web service to send messages to telegram.

Those are my templates.

Template: When Query mached

```bash
  name: {{rule.name}}
  status: CRITICAL
  date: {{context.date}}
  link: {{context.link}}
  hits: {{context.hits}}
```

Template: When recovered

```bash
  name: {{rule.name}}
  status: OK
  date: {{context.date}}
  link: {{context.link}}
  hits: {{context.hits}}
```

The result as I can see it on Telegram

```bash
  name: user-input
  status: OK
  date: 2023-02-21T08:52:02.958Z
  link: https://my-elasticsearch:9243/app/management/insightsAndAlerting/triggersActions/rule/**************
  hits:
```

Ejecuting the query by hand, without date range, I get that

```json
{
  "took": 96,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 215,
    "successful": 215,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10000,
      "relation": "gte"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Since I have size 0, I haven't real hits but I have the total amount of hits.

I have been reading [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/create-and-manage-rules.html#defining-rules-actions-variables%20without%20success) without success.

What is the proper way to get the total amount of hits and show it into my templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is *{{context.value}}*

```json
  name: {{rule.name}}
  status: OK
  date: {{context.date}}
  link: {{context.link}}
  hits: {{context.value}}
```